# How do I stream objects of incompatible types into a list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, incompatibletypeerror

My question is: Given a list of persons, return all students.

Here are my classes:

**Person class**

```
public class Person {
}
```

**Student class**

```
public class Student extends Person {
}
```

**Method**

```
public static List<Student> findStudents(List<Person> list) {


    return list.stream()
            .filter(person -> person instanceof Student)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'm getting a compile error: `incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds`

How do I return all the students from the list using stream without getting this error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return list.stream()
           .filter(Student.class::isInstance)
           .map(Student.class::cast)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It should be a cast there, otherwise, it's still a `Stream<Person>`. The `instanceof` check doesn't perform any cast.

`Student.class::isInstance` and `Student.class::cast` is just a preference of mine, you could go with `p -> p instanceof Student` and `p -> (Student)p` respectively.

Comment: brilliantly succinct

Comment: @AndrewTobilko this is one place where I wish the java language would pick-up things (like switch expressions), if you _know_ that `isInstance` passed, why do a `cast` also?.. 1+ otherwise

Comment: @Eugene hopefully we will get there with pattern matching. Unclear when it will be delivered though...

Answer (score 5):

You need a cast:

```
public static List<Student> findStudents(List<Person> list) 
{
    return list.stream()
               .filter(person -> person instanceof Student) 
               .map(person -> (Student) person)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative.

```
public static List<Student> findStudents(List<Person> list) 
{
    return list.stream()
            .filter(s -> Student.class.equals(s.getClass()))
            .map(Student.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: `s instanceof Student` is not the same as `Student.class.equals(s.getClass())`

Comment: Agree! they are two different sparks.  For this very filtering ask, this can fit here too.

Comment: Please provide some commentary around why this code solves the problem.